# Compare DateTime Lists, c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, compare

I have a List in C#

```
List<Dates>

public class Dates
{
    public DateTime Start {get; set;}
    public DateTime End {get; set;}
}
```

**In List:**

Start - End

1. 2014-03-17 09:00:00   -   2014-03-17 10:00:00
2. 2014-03-17 10:59:59   -   2014-03-17 11:44:59

How do I check if my startToCheck is between Start, the same to endToCheck to End to that list?

For example:

```
startToCheck = 2014-03-17 11:00:00
endToCheck = 2014-03-17 12:00:00
```

Obviously, my startToCheck is in List nr2, but is not find it.

I tried

```
if (Start <= startToCheck && End >= endToCheck)
```

But is not working...
Any help, please?

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Does it explode?

Comment: Do you want to know if your date range overlaps with any of the other date ranges?  Do you want to know if it is entirely contained within one of the given date ranges?

Comment: what is your current output and what is your expected output? "not working" doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: "How do I check if my startToCheck is between Start, the same to endToCheck to End to that list?" The grammar issues make this sentence very difficult to understand. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: Sorry about my grammar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect all overlaps:

```
yourList.Where(x=> x.Start <= endToCheck && x.End >= startToCheck)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to determine if any of the `Dates` value in the list are between that range.  If so you are looking for the `Any` method

```
if (theList.Any(x => x.Start <= endToCheck && x.End >= startToCheck) { 
  ...
}
```